# Zynqで割り込みが不調

Tags: linux, centos, zynq

Zynqの割り込みに悩んでいます。

システムの主要構成
Microzed, petalinux2016.2, CentOS7

GPIO割り込みは使用しません。
ドライバのCodingにUIOは使用しません。

IPの構成は簡単です:

- Zynq7
- Axi Interconnect
- Processor System Reset
- my_ip (ilc_ip_0)
- 4 IPのみ

my_ipの割り込み要求端子intrはZYNQのIRQ_F2P [0,0]に直接接続されています。

Myproject はvivadoから生成されるdesign_1_wrapper.hdfファイルが基礎になっています。
buildして4つのファイルが得られ、1個を追加しました。

- image.ub
- system.dtb   (不要？)
- ilcproc
- ilcdev.ko
- mystartup.sh

これらをSDCARDに格納、Resetします。
割り込み以外の機能は正常です。

以下に割り込み関連事項を抜き出しています。

#### 1. irqNo

次のファイルが取得でき

```
ilc(myprg)/subsystems/linux/hw-description/xparameters.h
```

これから

```
#define XPAR_FABRIC_ILC_IP_0_INTR_INTR 61
```

の記述を抜き出して
irqNo は61に確定しました。

#### 2. device tree

以下のDevice=treeが得られました：

```
ilc/subsystems/linux/device-tree/pl.dtsi
```

内容

```
 / {
 amba_pl: amba_pl {
 # address-cells = <1>;
 # size-cells = <1>;
 compatible = "simple-bus";
 ranges;
 ilc_ip_0: ilc_ip @ 43c00000 {
 compatible = "xlnx, ilc-ip-189.4";
 interrupt-parent = <& intc>;
 interrupts = <0 29 4>;
 reg = <0x43c00000 0x10000>;
 xlnx, s00-axi-ilc-ip-addr-width = <0x4>;
 xlnx, s00-axi-ilc-ip-data-width = <0x20>;
 };
 };
```

`interrupts = <0 29 4>;?` は何を意味するのでしょう？
以下のように推量しました：

```
  0: SPI
 29: 61-32 = 29 29 はGICがもたらすOffset？。しかし GICは使わないつもりです。
  4: Level interrupt. これはSPIなのだから0が正しいのではないか？
```

#### 3.

割り込み要求信号"intr" はedge信号が間違いなく出ていることをオッシロで確認しました。 Interruptは発生しません。

#### 4.

次に `/proc/interrupts` をチェックしてみました。

```
 21: 43 0 GIC       39 Level f8007100.adc
 61:  0 0 zynq-gpio 38 Edge  ilcdev
142:  0 0 GIC       35 Level f800c000.ocmc
```

zynq-gpio、これは何でしょう？
GPIO は構成に含まず全く関係ありません。
これはintrがGICを介さCPUに直接つながっていることを表していると考えました。
それともGICに代わるI/Fの仕様なのでしょうか？
いずれにしろGICの設定は全く行っていません。

ご示唆いただける方がいると助かります。

#### 5.

Linuxの関係programを一括して掲載します。
Xilinx社のTemplateそのままです。

```
static int ilcdev_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct resource *r_irq; /* Interrupt resources */
    struct resource *r_mem; /* IO mem resources */
    struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
    struct ilcdev_local *lp = NULL;

    int rc = 0;

    dev_info(dev, "Device Tree Probing\n");

    /* Get iospace for the device */
    r_mem = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
    if (!r_mem) {
        dev_err(dev, "invalid address\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    lp = (struct ilcdev_local *) kmalloc(sizeof(struct ilcdev_local), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!lp) {
        dev_err(dev, "Cound not allocate ilcdev device\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    dev_set_drvdata(dev, lp);

    lp->mem_start = r_mem->start;
    lp->mem_end = r_mem->end;

    if (!request_mem_region(lp->mem_start,
                lp->mem_end - lp->mem_start + 1,
                DRIVER_NAME)) {
        dev_err(dev, "Couldn't lock memory region at %p\n",
            (void *)lp->mem_start);
        rc = -EBUSY;
        goto error1;
    }

    lp->base_addr = ioremap(lp->mem_start, lp->mem_end - lp->mem_start + 1);
    if (!lp->base_addr) {
        dev_err(dev, "ilcdev: Could not allocate iomem\n");
        rc = -EIO;
        goto error2;
    }

    /* Get IRQ for the device */
    r_irq = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_IRQ, 0);
    if (!r_irq) {
        dev_info(dev, "no IRQ found\n");
        dev_info(dev, "ilcdev at 0x%08x mapped to 0x%08x\n",
            (unsigned int __force)lp->mem_start,
            (unsigned int __force)lp->base_addr);
        return 0;
    }
    lp->irq = r_irq->start;

    rc = request_irq(lp->irq, &ilcdev_irq, 0, DRIVER_NAME, lp);
    if (rc) {
        dev_err(dev, "testmodule: Could not allocate interrupt %d.\n",
            lp->irq);
        goto error3;
    }

    dev_info(dev,"ilcdev at 0x%08x mapped to 0x%08x, irq=%d\n",
        (unsigned int __force)lp->mem_start,
        (unsigned int __force)lp->base_addr,
        lp->irq);

    enable_irq(lp->irq);                // 2019/10/19 Added

    return 0;
error3:
    free_irq(lp->irq, lp);
error2:
    release_mem_region(lp->mem_start, lp->mem_end - lp->mem_start + 1);
error1:
    kfree(lp);
    dev_set_drvdata(dev, NULL);
    return rc;
}


static int __init ilcdev_init(void)
{
    int ret;

    printk("<1>Hello module world.\n");
    printk("<1>Module parameters were (0x%08x) and \"%s\"\n", myint, mystr);

    static struct resource foomatic_resources[] = {
        {
            .start  = 0x43c00000,
            .end    = 0x43c0ffff,
            .flags  = IORESOURCE_MEM,
            .name   = "io-memory"
        },
        {
            .start  = XPAR_FABRIC_ILC_IP_0_INTR_INTR,
            .end    = 20,
            .flags  = IORESOURCE_IRQ,
            .name   = "irq",
        }
    };

    pdev = platform_device_register_simple(DRIVER_NAME, 0, foomatic_resources,
        ARRAY_SIZE(foomatic_resources));              
    printk("ARRAY_SIZE(foomatic_resources) %x\n", ARRAY_SIZE(foomatic_resources));

    if (pdev == NULL)                       {                                                     
        printk("Adding platform device pdev\"%x\" failed\n", pdev);
        kfree(pdev);                                                             
        return -ENODEV;                                                          
    }
    else{
        printk("Adding platform device pdev\"%x\" successfull\n", pdev);
    }

    return platform_driver_register(&ilcdev_driver);
}
```

Comment: 名前からすると、これ [MicroZed 評価キット](https://japan.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/1-5lakcu.html) でしょうか。説明に書いてある [コミュニティサイト](http://www.microzed.org/) か、[英語版StackOverflowのzynq](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zynq) で聞いた方が早いのでは？

Comment: コメント欄の使用方法が分からず再送します。ふたつの間違いをしました。英語版サイトにするつもりが日本語サイトに投稿してしまったこと、Microzerdに追加してCPU名（ARM7－Cortex9）を明記すべきであったことです。であればResがいただけたかもしれません。

Comment: 日本語サイトで回答・コメントを得るのは難しいと思われます。英語版サイトでもコミュニティサイトでも良いですが、販売会社やメーカーのサポート窓口に直接問い合わせた方がもっと確実性は高いでしょう。